# Unable to modify machine.config file

Tags: asp.net, iis, machine.config

I want to improve performance of my ASP.NET web application and want to change "processModel" tag in machine.config. But I am unable to modify "machine.config" file located at framework directory. Though I have disabled "readonly" permission for the file, still it is not working.

Comment: What does it say when you try to edit?

Comment: You will need administrator permissions to edit machine.config.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is editable with admin permissions.

Answer (score 29):

You need to run the text editor that you are using to edit the `machine.config` file as `Administrator`.

Answer (score 3):

Open it using NotePad++ (or) NotePad. You have to run Notepad first in Administrator more (right click, select Run as administrator), then open machine.config

Ramkumar Thangavel.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio:

1. Right click on Visual Studio icon

(If you are right clicking on a taskbar icon, then you'll need to right click on the Visual Studio icon in the list as well)

2. Click **Run as administrator**
3. Within Visual Studio, click **File**->**Open**->**File...** (shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>)
4. From here, navigate to your machine.config. For .net 4, it's probably here: *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config*